# Backstretch.js and thumbnail sizes to reduce loading time

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails, responsive

I am using backstretch.js to set a featured image as a full size background image (as per [this tutorial](http://sridharkatakam.com/set-featured-image-full-sized-background-posts-pages-wordpress/)).

I would like to combine this approach with different thumbnail sizes in order to reduce loading time on mobile devices. I am wondering how I can manage this.

I guess the deciding line of code is the following from functions.php:

```
wp_localize_script( 'backstretch-set', 'BackStretchImg', array( 'src' => wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) ) );
```

I know that I can combine this code with an image size, like

```
wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'medium' ) ) );
```

But I don't know how to combine this either with mediaqueries or an if-query. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, theme customization is off topic here unless it relates to the default themes. Please ask this question on your themes support forums. Thanks

Comment: Why is this offtopic? Imho it is not a theme-specific question, but a question that can arise with every theme – and therefore the solution could be used with every theme.

Comment: Note that we do not handle questions:
generic PHP/MySQL/CSS/JavaScript/jQuery/TinyMCE issues and development - try StackOverflow http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Granted this is a borderline case, but I am not going to close vote yet. The solution will most likely not depend on WP as an evironment, but it might.

Comment: Well, having written one: It's mostly JS, but it does depend on WP core functions...

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use mediaqueries, you'd have to selectively dis- and enable DOM elements to which you have applied different images.

Rather than that, I'd recommend conditionally applying different images to the same element, i.e. the `<body>` and keeping the condition inside the JS.

[`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) is capable of passing several parameters to the script. I'd say pass several image sizes like so:

```
$script_parameters = array(
    'small' => wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), array(150, 150)),
    'medium' => wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), array(250, 250)),
    'large' => wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), array(350, 350))
);

wp_localize_script(
    'backstretch-set',
    'BackStretchImages',
    $script_parameters
);
```

And then expand the JS by a condition based on the screen/viewport width:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    // same as "document.documentElement.clientWidth" (vanilla JS)

    if ( 768 > viewportWidth ) {
        $("body").backstretch([BackStretchImages.small[0]],{duration:3000,fade:750});
    } else if ( 1024 > viewportWidth ) {
        $("body").backstretch([BackStretchImages.medium[0]],{duration:3000,fade:750});
    } else {
        $("body").backstretch([BackStretchImages.large[0]],{duration:3000,fade:750});
    }
});
```

You can add as many sizes as you wish and adjust the viewport boundaries to your liking.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, unfortunately it doesn't work yet. I added images sizes `add_image_size( 'small', 768 );
 add_image_size( 'medium', 1024 );
 add_image_size( 'large', 1400 );` and then regenerated the thumbnails, but checking with a resizer tool, backstretch is still using the original image when using a smaller device. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you reload the site after resizing?

Comment: Yes, I did. In order to find the problem, I made a jsfiddle in the non-WordPress-mode. Unfortunately, it does not work there, too. Like within WordPress, only "else" is shown.  http://jsfiddle.net/98t21Le8/

Comment: What does the console say?